# How can I map through two arrays in React at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am a beginner in React. I am using the json placeholder to fetch data using axios. I have two arrays in the state.

```
state = {
                posts : [],
                images : []

       };
```

After getting the data through axios I am using set state up update the value. 
Now, I want it all displayed in a card. If it were just one array I would've used map to display the content. Now I want an image from the images array to be displayed with each post. How could I go about this?

Comment: Why not combine both arrays into one and have a data object in the array that holds the post and it's image?

Comment: `posts.map((item, index)=> {const image = images[index]; ...})`

Answer (score 3):

You can create single array out of two array in this way.

```
const postsWithImage=this.state.posts.map(post=>{
return {
...post,
img: this.state.images.find(img=> img.id===post.imgid) // or some relation between posts and images
}

})
```

now further map the postsWithImage

Answer (score 2):

instead of separate arrays you could combine them and loop through like this :

```
const renderPosts = ()=>{
  return this.state.posts.map(post,index=>{
      return(
          <Card
             postImage={post.image}
             postData={post.data}
          />
       )
})
}
```

But if you are insisting on keeping them separate than you could do a nested loop like :

```
const templates = {
  template1: {
    items: [1, 2]
  },
  template2: {
    items: [2, 3, 4]
  },
};

const App = () => (
  <div>
    {
      Object.keys(templates).map(template_name => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>{template_name}</div>
            {
              templates[template_name].items.map(item => {
                return(<div>{item}</div>)
              })
            }
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
  </div>
);
```

Comment: This previous example did work for me. thanks.